# Acquiring EXIF data from multiple images within a folder

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I have created a function which uses PIL to extract all of the EXIF data within an image, next I need to modify the code so that I give the program a folder full of images and the code should extract the EXIF data from every image within and output into a file. I'm unsure of how to do this.

I have attempted to use a for loop on my function with the hope that it would iterate over the given images and return them one by one but have had zero luck.

```
import argparse
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def getMetaData(imgname, out):
        try:
                metaData = {}

                imgFile = Image.open(imgname)
                print ("Getting meta data...")
                info = imgFile._getexif()
                if info:
                        print ("found meta data!")
                        for (tag, value) in info.items():
                            tagname = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                            metaData[tagname] = value
                            if not out:
                                print (tagname, value)

                        if out:
                                print ("Outputting to file...")
                                with open(out, 'w') as f:
                                    for (tagname, value) in metaData.items():
                                            f.write(str(tagname)+"\t"+\
                                                    str(value)+"\n")
        except:
                print ("Failed")
def Main():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

        parser.add_argument("imageName", help="name of an image file.")
        print(parser)
        parser.add_argument("outputFile", help="dump data out to file")
        print(parser)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        if args.imageName:
                print("hello")
                getMetaData(args.imageName, args.outputFile)
        else:
                print (parser.usage)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html#action

Comment: May I commend `exiftool` to you? Try `exiftool *.jpg`